# How can i import 150GB database after deleting ibdata1,logfile in MYSQL?

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.1

I have 150GB database and my ibdata1 file size is 240GB so i want shrink the ibdata1 file so for that i have to export the DB and then drop the tables and then stop mysql, delete the ibdata1 file and then start the =MYSQL again and import the DB again.

If the above solution is correct how can i export and import such huge DB also there is partitioned created in the DB table.

And I am also not sure that i will not loose any data in during this process.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you exported it using mysqldump, then that file probably includes the CREATE statements needed to recreate the table before, then followed by INSERTs to reload it.

Suggest you also add this to my.ini during the process (before the reload):

```
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

Or... Is your problem that you don't have a spare 150GB if disk space do even do the dump??  If so, you have "painted yourself into a corner".

If you can get another machine with 150GB (or more) of spare room, then run the mysqldump from that machine, writing to that machine.

As for "there is partitioned created in the DB table"; let's see the details.  SHOW CREATE TABLE would be useful.

Comment: we already have one external drive and we are saving dump file in that drive.